# How get NSDate from NSString timeStyle formatted with locale settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can I get a NSDate (time) from a NSString formatted according to the regional settings? Let me explain. Based on the regional settings of the device, I have to convert myString to NSDate in HH:ss (italian format)

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
 dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
 [dateFormatter setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleIdentifier]]];
```

my NSString can be: @"2014-01-01 6:15 PM" or @"2014-01-01 18:15" or @"2014-01-01 6:15 MUU" or ???? 
My result must be: @"01/01/2014 18:15"

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"????"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myNSString];
```

How do I get the regional format to properly set the formatter?

Comment: Please search. There are countless examples of convert a date/time string from one format to another.

Comment: Are two days that I try but I can't find a clear solution. I have made many attempts but none with the desired results

Comment: You need two formatters. One to read the original string to create the `NSDate` and the second to convert the `NSDate` to the new format.

Comment: @maddy I solved the problem, the solution was so simple ... The NSDateFormatter class is really powerful as it is complex to understand, but when you understand the operation is fantastic !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you must write something like that:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Italy"]];//include you're location from what country time you want
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"New NSDate (NSDate): %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* stringDate  = @"January 1, 2000 at 9:10 PM";    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; 

NSDate *tempDate      = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tempDate];
```